# Array error for fisher-yates shuffle algorithm

Tags: c#, arrays

I was trying to make c# code for [modern fisher yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Modern_method), I want to use [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle) but it's too complicated for me so i simplified to code below, but i got some error "[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array." and i don't know what's wrong. please help

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static Random _random = new Random();
    static void Shuffle(int[] array)
    {
    int p = array.Length;
    for (int n = p; n > 1 ; n--)
    {
        int r = _random.Next(1, n);
        int t = array[r];
        array[r] = array[n];
        array[n] = t;
    }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        Shuffle(array);
        foreach (int value in array)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: initial value of `n` is `array.Length` and inside the loop you are indexing `array[n]`. Thats the exception.

Comment: Arrays in C# are zero indexed. So start from n=p-1 to 0 for the error to disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int p = array.Length;
 for (int n = p; n > 1 ; n--)`

These two lines are the problem. Arrays are 0-indexed, so by starting at the length of the array, you're already out-of-bounds.  You can fix it by immediatly subtracting one from `p`, like so: `int p = array.Length - 1;`.  Also you should let `n` go to 0 in order to reach all elements of the array: `n >= 0`.